# Could not setcwd() (errno 2: No such file or directory)

Tags: android, gradle

After running my project I encounter following error in android studio.

Do you know the reason?

```
10:04:15 PM: Executing task 'installDebug'...

Could not set process working directory to '/Users/mahdir/.gradle/daemon/4.8/:app': could not setcwd() (errno 2: No such file or directory)
10:04:15 PM: Task execution finished 'installDebug'.
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I saw this error when I had an invalid "Gradle project:" specified as part of a Gradle Run/Debug Configuration in AS 3.2.  It's a free text field but better to use the folder icon to the right of the field to ensure you are selecting a valid project.

Answer (score 29):

For me

1. Close the project and remove it from recent project list.
2. Go to the project directory and remove .gradle & .idea directory.
3. Import this as existing project again.

Answer (score 15):

For me **Invalidate Cache / Restart** worked.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the module is not properly selected in the run/debug configuration.
Before you try the whole unlink/link roundtrip just do:

1. Open the `Run/Debug Configuration` dialog for the config in question by

- clicking on the dropdown to the top left (see [Run/Debug Configuration Dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71Rji.png))
- clicking on `Edit Configurations...` (see [Configuration Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7zRx.png))

2. Click on the icon right next to the `Gradle project` field and re-select the module of your choice (see [Gradle project selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hq4Ph.png))
3. Try running the run/debug configuration again.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I had a Gradle project in the project I had opened, but hadn't imported it (as a Gradle project).

I fixed the issue by:

1. right-click on the `build.gradle` file in the Project window
2. select "Import Gradle project"
3. run tasks directly from the Gradle tool window